# acts_as_commentable_with_threading uninitialized constant Post::Comment Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-commentable

I have upgraded my application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.1.3. I had **acts_as_commentable_with_threading** and **awesome_nested_set** as plugins. Now I have added in GemFile for Rails 3.1.3 as below

```
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'
```

I have code in the model as below

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_commentable
end
```

The migration for **acts_as_commentable_with_threading** is already applied in the database.

I have statement in the view as

```
<%= pluralize(post.root_comments.size, "comment") %> on this post
```

When I try to load that view I get error at that line as

```
uninitialized constant Post::Comment
```

What can be the problem. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There still isn't a solution to this? I just started getting this error.

Comment: @jab No man. I didn't check further as I abandoned the work on that project.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to run the generator and the migration afterwards:

```
rails generate acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration
or
rails generate acts_as_commentable_upgrade_migration
```

and after:

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

It's first steps of [github repo instructions](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading)